# Remove Select2 Bootstrap CSS Box Shadow

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

I use Select2 Bootstrap CSS.
But i get box shadow in my combobox.

[image]

How to remove that?

I use :

- select2 3.5.2
- Bootstrap 3.3.2
- JQuery 1.11.3

Here is my code :

```
<link href="../css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../css/select2-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../js/select2.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.select2').select2();
        });
    </script>
```

I already change all version to fit in the Select2 Bootstrap's Documentation.
But it still not work.

Thank you.

Comment: plesae share live link/demo link where you are facing this issue then we can help..thanx

Comment: Just set box-shadow: none; to the class .form-control. Use Inspect element or a similar tool.

Answer (score 1):

Use Inspect element and check particular div apply css box-shadow:none;